# Pegar diretório atual em quer PHAR é executado

Tags: php

Muitos gerenciadores em PHP são disponibilizados em arquivos PHAR, que são instalados globalmente via Composer ou nas variáveis de ambiente do sistema operacional.

É o caso do próprio Composer, e também do PHPUnit.

Em qualquer diretório posso executar o comando `phpunit` que ele vai recolher o diretório em qual executei e o arquivo phpunit.xml.

A pergunta é justamente essa, em um phar ou executável PHP como pego o diretório em que ele foi executado? Pois na maioria das vezes o diretório não é o mesmo que o phar. A solução deve funcionar em todos sistemas.

Pesquisei mas não encontrei nada parecido. Podem ajudar?

Comment: isso não serve? http://php.net/manual/en/phar.running.php

Comment: Acho que a função `getcwd` faz isso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é isso mesmo, publique a resposta para que eu possa marcar como certa.